# Want to fetch field from AggregateQuery

Tags: apex, soql, customsetting, aggregate, aggregateresult

I created a Custom Settings and add some records in it. On the basis of that  value i write an aggregate query and i want to store that field value in String.

```
    // List to fetch all records from Custom settings
List<Region_and_Country_Mapping__c> csList = Region_and_Country_Mapping__c.getall().values();

// Created a map to store fields of custom link
Map<string, string> countryCodeVsCountryNameMap = new Map<string, string>();
for(Region_and_Country_Mapping__c cs : csList) {
        if(cs.Region_Name__c == regionSelected) {
             countryCodeVsCountryNameMap.put(cs.Country_Code__c, cs.Country_Name__c);
        }
 }

 AggregateResult[] resultsStateCount = [SELECT BillingCity, count(Id) from Account WHERE BillingCountryCode IN :countryCodeVsCountryNameMap.keySet() GROUP BY BillingCity];
 for(AggregateResult ar : resultsStateCount) { 
         ClientGeoLocationDetailWrapper clientGeoDetail = new ClientGeoLocationDetailWrapper();
          string cityName = String.valueOf(ar.get('BillingCity'));
          string cityCount = String.valueOf(ar.get('expr0'));

          // want to fetch country code
          string CountryCode = BillingCountryCode
```

In Code i clearly mention all senarios please review and help me to fetch BillingCountryCode

Comment: You are not querrying `BillingCountryCode` in SOQL

Comment: Yes because if i query `BillingCountryCode` then i have to group by with BillingCountryCode which i don't want.

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to get `BillingCountryCode` field, you will have to include that field in your SOQL query and you will have to group that field as well.

So you will have to change your SOQL query to below.

```
AggregateResult[] resultsStateCount = [SELECT BillingCity,BillingCountryCode,count(Id) countId from Account WHERE BillingCountryCode IN :countryCodeVsCountryNameMap.keySet() GROUP BY BillingCity, BillingCountryCode];
```

And then you can get the value of `BillingCountryCode` as you do for other fields

```
string cityName = String.valueOf(ar.get('BillingCity'));
string cityCount = String.valueOf(ar.get('countId'));
// want to fetch country code
string CountryCode = String.valueOf(ar.get('BillingCountryCode'));
```

Comment: i dont want to group by BillingCountryCode

Comment: Without grouping it, you won't be able to get the value of `BillingCountryCode` from `AggregateResult`. If you don't group by `BillingCountryCode`, the value of `BillingCountryCode` would be different for the records in a single group i.e. All the records with same `BillingCity` can have different `BillingCountryCode`, so in that case, what will be your logic to pick which value from that set of values ?